# Why won't my UIPickerView items display when I change @objc inference to off (on project I converted to Swift 4)?

Tags: swift, uipickerview, inference

Here's a partial snapshot of my app running after converting it to Swift 4.2 (from 3.x).  You can see that the items in my UIPickerView do actually display properly.

[image: CYaPass UIPickerView]

However, if I update the project and change the objc inference to off (instead of on) -- XCode suggests this setting be changed -- then my UIPickerView does not display the items although they are in contained in the list.

[image: set objc inference to off]

**Snapshot of UIPickerView Which Seems to Be Empty**

Here's the app running showing what looks like an empty UIPickerView, but as you can see I've chosen to Delete an item.  However, behind it you can see that the UIPickerView seems to be empty.

[image: UIPickerView seems to be empty, but is not]

Here is the basic code that loads the items in the UIPickerView

```
public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    if (siteKeyPickerValues != nil){
        return siteKeyPickerValues.count
    }
    return 0
}

public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?{
    if (siteKeyPickerValues != nil && siteKeyPickerValues.count > 0){
        return siteKeyPickerValues[row]
    }
    return nil
}
```

**siteKeyPickerValues (String Array) Is Initialized**

The siteKeyPickerValues does seem to be initialized properly too. Here it is running in debug mode with the @objc inferenece turned off:
[image: siteKeyPickerValues has values]

Comment: "and change the objc inference to off (instead of on)" You should change it to default and you should make sure that your view controller explicitly adopts UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate.

Comment: Yes, I did change it to default but that causes the same issue and I assumed it was setting it to off (under Swift 4 build) so I just wrote up the question that way.  The point is that it fails unless it is set explicitly to on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously (under Swift 3.x and previous versions of XCode), I had the MainControllerView set up in the following way and it worked fine:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate
```

After the comment from @matt, I simply made one change and added the `UIPickerViewDataSource` like the following:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, 
UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate
```

I rebuilt with the @objc inference set to default (or off) and ran the program and now I see the expected items in the UIPickerView.

[image: uipickerview displays items]

That solves the problem.
I wonder if that is a recent change or if just happened to work before?